# Is "letterataggine" a correct Italian word?

Tags: word-meaning, single-words

I've read *letterataggine* in a sentence by Guglielmo Giannini (from *Le Vespe*), but this is the only reference in which I can find this word used (also without any explanation).

Can someone tell me more about this? (I think that it is an error by Giannini).

EDIT: On suggestion here is the quote in which I found *letterataggine*. Giannini was talking about the editor Longanesi, whom he despised, defining him:

*«l'editore più maleducato d'Italia. Varrebbe
forse la pena di dire qualcosa di più sul conto di questo altero bassotto così
pieno di **letterataggine**: ma forse è meglio fregarsene di lui altamente; e
altamente appunto perché si tratta d'un bassotto»*

Comment: When you ask a question about the use of a word in a specific text, remember to **always report the full sentence** in which it appears, possibly with some context.

Comment: Seconding Federico: can you give a complete quote, both of the sentence where you found the word and of its source?

Answer (score 5):

It's not a correct Italian word in the sense that it is not in the dictionaries. But "being in dictionaries" is only partially related to the ability of a word to convey meaning (and so be a functional part of the language).

This word is built using standard rules of the Italian language (in this case applying the suffix [*-aggine*](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/aggine/) to the adjective [*letterato*](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/letterato1/)), so it is fairly clear its meaning: "the fact of being lettered" or "a thing done by someone lettered" ("lettered" in the sense of being well-read, well educated or otherwise scholarly).

I will add that the excessive length of the word and the general connotation of the suffix *-aggine* makes me suspect that this word has been used in a humorous fashion, something like "The kind of crazy thing that only extremely well educated people write/do". I doubt that Giannini is making a mistake here, but rather that he decided to create a new word (using the established rules of the language) to better make his point. Context is key to understand neologisms.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is an actual word, it looks like Giannini wanted to give the word "letteratura" the same meaning of "something stupid or bad" , like in the sentence "è una stupidaggine" (it's a stupid thing). "Letterataggine" so looks like he is giving a bad connotation about literature.